# MTKView in Cocoa doesn't draw in Retina

Tags: swift, cocoa, metal

I have a MTKView in Cocoa.

I'm displaying a texture with drawable.texture - but the texture only shows over a quarter of the screen - Non-Retina.

Do I need to do any additional setup to get this to work?

```
class MyView : MTKView
```

The following code has no-affect:

```
let scale = NSScreen.mainScreen()!.backingScaleFactor
var s = frame.size
s.width *= scale
s.height *= scale

metalLayer.contentsScale = scale
metalLayer.framebufferOnly = false
metalLayer.drawableSize = s
```

Update:

Here's the method I have to load the texture from the image:

```
func textureFromImage(image: NSImage, inout tex:MTLTexture?) {


    let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: self.device!)
    do {
        tex = try textureLoader.newTextureWithCGImage(image.CGImage, options: nil)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Can't load texture")
    }
}
```

and the code to present:

```
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(originalTexture, atIndex: 0)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, atIndex: 1)
    commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit();
```

All of the sizes for the original input image and texture are the same size as the view.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you're getting the texture's contents into the drawable (drawing, blitting, etc)? Is there a difference in size between the source texture and the drawable?

Comment: Sure, added some code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the contentScaleFactor for the view to 1.

Answer (score 0):

5 years late to the party, but I just had this problem because I called
`renderEncoder.setViewport(MTLViewport(originX: 0, originY: 0, width: Double(viewport.x), height: Double(viewport.y), znear: -1.0, zfar: 1.0))` with viewport.x/y being in points instead of pixels.

To render properly I multiplied x/y by screen scale (x2 for retina).